# Removing duplicate JAR's-Mavenbuild

Tags: java, spring, maven, maven-3

I am building my application and I could see different version of same jar getting downloaded and my ear size is growing very huge. Could you please let me know is there any easy shortcut to remove old version and keep only the latest version of jar's?

I have analyzed using mvn:dependencytree .

Answer (score 0):

first, maven will only end up using [a single version](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) of a jar if multiple versions are dependencies, so you shouldn't be getting multiple versions of the same jar in your ear.

second, you can use `<exclusions>` on your dependencies to avoid dependencies you don't want.

Comment: Are you sure maven will take latest dependency? Is there any doc to support this?

Comment: @Lokesh - i guess it's not the latest.  there is a whole algorithm for the mediation process described in the documentation http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html